# How do I screen for #Value! error in macro? (Currently not being recognized)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run a macro based on some values in a sheet. Sometimes when I update the sheet with external links this line kicks back a 'type mismatch' error when cell F23 is showing '#Value!':

```
If Range("F23").Value = 1 Then
```

I figured it was because the code was trying to compare and 'error' with an 'integer'. I tried screening for this with ISERROR but it doesn't return True and I can't find another way to get around it on Google. Is there some solution to this where I could screen for the cell showing '#Value!' before running this line so my macro doesn't break?

Comment: simple solution is before if place "on error resume next" and after end if "on error goto 0"

Comment: Be careful with `On Error Resume Next`. Misuse sentences you to a lifetime of misery.

Answer (score 2):

First you test the cell with `IsError(theCell)`. Then check to see if it is a `#VALUE` error.

For example, to check for `#VALUE`;

```
Function errValueTest(rg As Range) As Boolean
    If IsError(rg) Then
        If rg.Value = CVErr(2015) Then
            errValueTest = True
        Else
            MsgBox "some other error"
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Or you could use `Select Case` to return the type of error present.  All kinds of possibilities.

See the late Chip Pearson's discussion on [Returning Errors from VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ReturningErrors.aspx) for a more detailed discussion.

Comment: Thanks! For reasons unknown the problem has randomly stopped happening, but if it pops back up again I'll give this a shot.