# Vlookup Range Without Getting #NA Value if is Not Found

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that works perfectly fine, but how do I make it to avoid getting #NA Value.

Every time I run the code, VBA will delete the existing value and change it to #NA while it doesn't have to be changed if there is no match.

this is my current code

```
Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Existing")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Columns("A:AJ")
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Existing")
    Dim dlRow As Long
    dlRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 2 To lastRowSourceSheet
        dws.Cells(i, "P").Value = Application.VLookup(dws.Cells(i, "A").Value, srg, 35, 0)
    Next i
    
    For i = 2 To lastRowSourceSheet
        dws.Cells(i, "Q").Value = Application.VLookup(dws.Cells(i, "A").Value, srg, 36, 0)
    Next i
```

I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: updated with tested code.

You only need to check for a match once:

```
Sub BlahBlah()
    '.....
    Dim wb As Workbook, sws As Worksheet, dws As Worksheet, i As Long, m As Variant

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set sws = wb.Sheets("Source")  'really the same worksheet?
    Set dws = wb.Sheets("Source")
    
    For i = 2 To dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        m = Application.Match(dws.Cells(i, "A").Value, sws.Columns("A"), 0)
        If Not IsError(m) Then  'got a match in ColA?
            AddIfNotNA dws.Cells(i, "P"), sws.Cells(m, 35).Value
            AddIfNotNA dws.Cells(i, "Q"), sws.Cells(m, 36).Value
        End If
    Next i
    '...
    '...
End Sub

'Add value `v` to cell `c` if `v` is not NA#
Sub AddIfNotNA(c As Range, v)
    If Not IsError(v) Then
        c.Value = v 'not any type of error: add value
    Else
        If v <> CVErr(xlErrNA) Then c.Value = v 'not #NA  -add value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually column 35 and 36 were a lookup results so there are #NA. What i need here is to copy column AI and AJ to P and Q respectively without copying the #NA Result. Or maybe could you change the code to visible cells only? So, that the vlookup will be applied on the visible cells that i wanted. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your post has this data all on the same sheet. Is that actually the case?

Comment: yes, it's all in the same sheet

Comment: And all in one table?  If that's the case then why not read directly from (eg) `sws.Cells(i, 35)`  what is that additional lookup doing?

Comment: See edit above for how to populate a cell with a value as long as that value is not `NA#`

Comment: It's giving compile error sub or function not defined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257250/discussion-between-little-turtle-and-tim-williams).

Comment: "error sub or function not defined" on which line?

Comment: on AddIfNotNA dws.cells(i, "p") and when debug it specifically block the AddIfNotNA

Comment: Did you add the code for `AddIfNotNA` to your code module?

Comment: i copied all of your code to the module

Comment: Updated my code - posted code tested and working...

Answer (score 1):

You only need to test your result before writing them:

```
For i = 2 To lastRowSourceSheet
    If Not Application.IsNa(Application.VLookup(dws.Cells(i, "A").Value, srg, 35, 0)) Then
        dws.Cells(i, "P").Value = Application.VLookup(dws.Cells(i, "A").Value, srg, 35, 0)
    End If
Next i

For i = 2 To lastRowSourceSheet
    If Not Application.IsNa(Application.VLookup(dws.Cells(i, "A").Value, srg, 36, 0)) Then
        dws.Cells(i, "Q").Value = Application.VLookup(dws.Cells(i, "A").Value, srg, 36, 0)
    End If
Next i
```

Another way to test for errors is with the `IsError()` method. See for example: [How do I screen for #Value! error in macro? (Currently not being recognized)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65510008/how-do-i-screen-for-value-error-in-macro-currently-not-being-recognized)

So you might prefer, instead:

```
Dim x as Variant 'Or String, Long, etc.
For i = 2 To lastRowSourceSheet
    x = Application.VLookup(dws.Cells(i, "A").Value, srg, 35, 0)
    If Not IsError(x) Then
        dws.Cells(i, "P").Value = x
    End If
Next i
'... and likewise for next statement
```

Looping cell by cell is not always the most performant approach in VBA/Excel so if you many cells it may be possible to speed this up a lot with additional improvements in your solution.

Comment: both the ways giving run-time error: Sub or Function is not defined on the Vlookup statement

Comment: I've added `Application.VLookup` instead of `VLookup` to the examples.